# How to return a list with indexes in python function

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

If I have a list in python, can I return the list along with indexes using a function:

```
def list_my(G):
    nodes = list(G.nodes())
    return nodes
```

This above code returns only the nodes:

['Hi','hello','be','bye','in'...]
while I want it as:

['Hi',0, 'hello',1, 'be',2, 'bye',3, 'in',4, ...]

Can anyone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a for loop:

```py
def list_my(G):
    result = list()
    for i, node in enumerate(G.nodes()):
        result.extend((node, i))
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks, its working but its printing the results twice:

Comment: like [a, b, c, a 1, b 2, c 3]